# How can state be updated with string and the update state

Tags: reactjs

I'm doing here is updating the state with the string which work something like the following:

```
 changeColorE(e){
    this.setState({error:"style={{backgroundColor :" +this.state.colorNew +"}}"},()=>console.log("-------",this.state.error))
 }
```

In render I've

```
const { error }=this.state;
```

I get the error here **{error}**  it says

```
Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected "..."

<div className="col-2" {error}   onClick={this.changeColorE.bind(this)}></div>
```

How can **{error}**  something like that be done for an element? Am I going the right way or whats the right way?
Why it doesn't work with just **{error}** and not **{...error}** ?

the **errorClr** doesn't work i'm passing the error to it n declared

```
    const { error }=this.state;
    const  {errorClr}={style:{color : {error}}}; // this doesnt work the way?

<div className="col-8" {...errorClr}>Please enter valid data</div>
```

The **color proptery** doesn't reflect.I've done no setstate. Can we not do something of this sort **{style:{color : {error}}}** ?

Comment: Have you tried using this.state.error?

Comment: I' using const {error}=this.state so just error must workout

Comment: Its because your placing your styles in "" qoutations this means the error state is being ignored.

Comment: u mean if any updated state if in string gets ignored?

Answer (score 0):

Dont save the style as a string, however save it as an object like

```
changeColorE(e){
    this.setState({
         error: {
             style: { backgroundColor : this.state.colorNew } 
         }
    },()=> console.log("-------",this.state.error))
 }
```

and then use it like

```
<div className="col-2" {...error} onClick={this.changeColorE.bind(this)}></div>
```

Comment: doesn't work :( y have u " +this.state.colorNew +" as string? y v require ...error instead of just error

Comment: Sorry for the error, Please check the updated answer

Comment: Worked .can u please explain y not string n y object ? y {...error} not {error} ?Because of {...error} default error not getting applied

Comment: Properties in jsx cannot be passed like `{error}`, either you spread the props or specify as `error={error}`, hence you must use an object which you can spread like `{...error}`

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html#specifying-attributes-with-jsx and https://www.reactenlightenment.com/react-jsx/5.7.html